# how to hide/show layers in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I want to be able to hide and show/layers in Mapbox like this example provided by Mapbox.... https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/

I have some vector data saved as a tile set in Mapbox, but I don't know where to find the URL is shown in the example below as 'mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr'. Can anyone tell me how to find it for my own data?

```
// Wait until the map has finished loading.
map.on('load', () => {
// Add a custom vector tileset source. This tileset contains
// point features representing museums. Each feature contains
// three properties. For example:
// {
//     alt_name: "Museo Arqueologico",
//     name: "Museo Inka",
//     tourism: "museum"
// }
map.addSource('museums', {
type: 'vector',
url: 'mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr` is a reference to a mapbox custom vector tileset.  You can make one of your own by uploading data in Mapbox Studio: https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/tilesets/. Mapbox will then serve this tileset for your map to consume.

However, this isn't necessary to toggle map layers using the technique shown in the example.  `map.setLayoutProperty()` can be used to show or hide any layer, including layers that came with the base style, or layers added after the fact using vector tiles or geojson sources.

If you are working with small/simple data, you may want to just [add a geojson source and layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/external-geojson/), and then use `setLayoutProperty()` to show and hide it as in the example.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. What if I have a raster tile set that I want to add to a map as a layer? I have already uploaded the Geotiff into Mapbox and it is visible in my tile sets. But I am unsure how to add this to my basemap. I can add it in the styles studio but does this allow me to turn the layer on and off. Do I need to add it later after the map has loaded to be able to toggle its visibility?

Comment: I've got it. I have managed to create the following map with layers.. https://codepen.io/charlie-enright/pen/ZExKOGB. Do you know how I might add buttons to be able to toggle the layers on and off. I have been looking at this example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/. But it seems like this might only work with vector layers, whereas mine are raster.

Comment: ah its ok, I got the toggle buttons working for raster too. https://codepen.io/charlie-enright/pen/ZExKOGB